# Java client-server application which show message in taskbar when new record updated in db

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to create a client-server application using java where i will give a link on webpage and on click client can download and install that application in his PC.it will stay in task-bar and display message when new data is added to server.

Comment: good luck (and what is your question?)

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible in Java6: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/